Flask-SQLAlchemy: declared_attr does change the __tablename__ but is pointing to or still accessing the same table
I have two tables, user and user_us in a sqlite file. Both the tables have the same structure. I tried to use a class and an inherited class to access both using declared attribute decoration. If the table which gets accessed does not change by this declared attribute then what is the point of doing it? What am I doing wrong?
class User(db.Model):
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls) -> str:
        return str(cls.__name__.lower())

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class User_us(User):
    pass
print(f'Test state: {User_us.__tablename__} {(User_us.__table__.name)}') 

gives output:
Test state: user_us user

I was expecting:
Test state: user_us user_us and the table accessed to be of user_us.
Using:
Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.1.1
SQLAlchemy==2.0.30


After exploring a bit deeper, I found out that the declared_attr is not needed here as internally the classname becomes lowercased and used the way I am trying to declare it here for __tablename__ Reference
To inherit a class and reuse it, the elegant approach I found is to use __abstract__ = True for a general_model and then inherit it in the other two classes.
class general_model(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class User(general_model):
    pass

class User_US(general_model):
    pass

print(f'Test state: {user_us.__tablename__} {(user_us.__table__.name)}') 

This works and prints.
Test state: user_us user_us like I expected.
